# How to tell if my python program has written anything to sys.stdout or not (within the same program)?

Tags: python, io, stdout, file-descriptor

I'm making a program that has different control flows depending on whether  anything was written to `sys.stdout` or not. I made this program first in my Mac and I could do this

```py
pos = sys.stdout.tell()
exec(some_code, globals)
if pos == sys.stdout.tell():
    # ...
```

But it turns out that I could not use `tell()` method on Linux and that's a problem for me. How can I tell if `sys.stdout` has been touched or not in this case?

One think I can come up with is to make a wrapper class for both `sys.stdout` and `sys.stdout.buffer` to monitor all writing calls, although I'm not sure it's robust way of doing it.

Or I think I may can give `contextlib.redirect_stdout` a try. But I am not sure how can I make use of it..

EDIT:
I'm working on this utility https://github.com/bombs-kim/pythonp. The feature I'm trying to implement is to automatically write the last expression of `some_code` in `exec(some_code, globals)` to stdout when there was no output to stdout.

Comment: Your solution of using a wrapper class sounds like the correct approach in this case.

Comment: Why do you ask, and what is the use case? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53994438/edit) your question (providing some [MCVE] and giving the actual commands you are using) to motivate it.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I tell if sys.stdout has been touched or not in this case?

**You cannot**, because stdout might have been [redirected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) or in a [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) (by the command used in your shell to run your Python script). For example, your user could have redirected stdout to [`/dev/null`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) (see [null(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/null.4.html)) by running your `script.py` as `script.py > /dev/null` for example, and then your question don't even make any sense. And your `stdout` might even be a socket, a fifo, a device, etc. Also, the [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)-ution of `some_code` might change `stdout` (e.g. close it, redirect it using [`os.dup2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=dup2#os.dup2), redefine itself the `stdout` Python object, etc...)

Also, your program might not even be run in a terminal (think of a [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) job, or running your program with `at` or `ssh`). See also t[he tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page.

The stdout [standard stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) is (conventionally) set up by the invoking process (usually, but not always, some shell) which has [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)-ed and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)-ed your script.

And that is not Linux specific, it is the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy). You may want to read some Unix or Linux programming book (such as [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)).

You might detect the case when your *stdout* is a terminal, by using [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html). But that certainly does not cover all the possible use-cases.

Linux has `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more) and the stdout is also `/dev/stdout` a.k.a. `/proc/self/fd/1` on which you might do a [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) (and of course you could directly do `fstat` on `STDOUT_FILENO` which is 1). But even that won't cover all the possible use-cases.

Have you thought of the case when your program monitors itself (e.g. `pythonp pythonp` ...) ?

I am not sure to understand your real goals, but they ring the [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem) in my head and your problem could be undecidable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If there is no way I can directly monitor file descriptor 1 as you said, do you think I can make a wrapper for python's `sys.stdout` object to detect every write event?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment! What about the redirection to `/dev/null` mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Sorry If I didn't make much sense in my comment. It's not important whether the end user redirect stdout to /dev/null or not in my case. As I previously said, I think I just need a hook for writing event to python's sys.stdout. Seems like one of the commenters on my question understood my intention.

Comment: And I just want to detect write events within the same program that called `exec`.

Comment: @bombs im curious now as well, it seems like you can wrap around sys.stdout and intercept any call to it

Comment: @NEGRKITAEC When I asked this question I wasn't sure that would be a right thing to do. I thought there may be some pitfalls to simply wrapping `sys.stdout` so some sophisticated approach is needed. Also, you can not catch all write events by wrapping `sys.stdout`. For example, `os.fdopen(1, 'w').write()`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it on my own by wrapping both `sys.stdout.write`, `sys.stdout.buffer.write` in python3.

```py
import sys
write = sys.stdout.write

write_called = [False]


def make_write_hook(old_writer, flag: list):
    self = old_writer.__self__

    def new_writer(value):
        self.write = old_writer
        flag[0] = True
        old_writer(value)
    return new_writer


sys.stdout.write = make_write_hook(sys.stdout.write, write_called)
sys.stdout.buffer.write = make_write_hook(
    sys.stdout.buffer.write, write_called)

history = []
history.append(write_called[0])
print("hello world")
history.append(write_called[0])
print(history)

# ### output
# hello world
# [False, True]
```

By my observation on cpython's standard library code, python's convention is that all writes to standard output should done by calling `sys.stdout.write` or `sys.stdout.buffer.write`, not directly calling something like `os.fdopen(1, 'w').write`. This is my temporary conclusion and I would like anyone who knows python better than me confirm this. Thank you everybody!